# Opening image file in jsp file useing href

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

hi i am trying to open the image file in jsp page with this code

```
<a href="file:///D:/FTP/ScanDoc/1018/1365171701_table-add_871716093.png" target="_blank">abc</a>
```

but due to some problem this code not working . 
when i try this in html page this is working properly . what may the problem ??
is that any other way. 
I am new with jsp .

Answer (score 2):

This is because the browser doesn't allow you to access client files when you are using the http protocol (see more on [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).  For example:

If you have a browser open with URL `http(s)://.....` then accessing client files using the local file system doesn't work.

But if the browser URL starts with `file:///...`  then that means that this is a static page located in the users filesystem, and therefore the browser allows to access the file.

Have a look also [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally)

You can display a picture from the local(server's local filesystem) file system using a Servlet.

Comment: sorry about my English , i use file:/// but it's not opening the image.

Comment: of course it doesn't because the jsp runs on the server and you access it using a client. This will never work with a jsp. (Also note that there is a problem in the path of your img tag - use `//` to display a single `/` for file separator)

Answer (score 1):

JSP pages runs on a local server.

You can't include or use files on your computer outside of this server (not even using full paths like D:\somefile.png).
Try adding this picture to your local server and include it properly.